# Store multiple columns result query in array variable

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I would like to store the result of a query in a arraylist of a custom type.

The created type is:

```
create type statement_part AS (
statementid integer,
statement_value_date timestamp,
statement_last_transmission  timestamp);
```

and the procedure code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.get_bank_statements_downloadable_state
(
folderID integer,
date1 timestamp without time zone,
date2 timestamp without time zone
)

RETURNS bank_day[]
LANGUAGE plpgsql

AS $get_bank_statements_downloadable_state$


declare

    statements_part_array statement_part[];
    temp_statements_part_array statement_part[];
    statements_part_element statement_part;
    bank_day_array bank_day[];
    bank_day_element bank_day;
    nb_days integer;

begin
    
    
    
    select array(bast_id::integer), array(bast_valuedate), array(bast_lasttransmission) 
    from bast_bankstatement
    inner join baac_bankaccount
    on bast_baac_id = baac_bankaccount.baac_id 
    where baac_folder_id = folderid
    and (bast_valuedate between date1 and date2)
    and bast_state = 1
    into statements_part_array;
    
    foreach statements_part_element in array statements_part_array loop
    RAISE NOTICE 'Array list(%)', statements_part_array;
    end loop;
    
    nb_days := (select * from DATE_PART('day', AGE(date1, date2)) AS days);

    for dayCounter in 0..nb_days-1 loop
        --on met dans notre tableau temporaire les relevés banque valides du jour du cabinet
        temp_statements_part_array := 
            (
            select * 
            from statements_part_array
            where statements_part_array.statement_value_date = date1+dayCounter
            );
        if count(temp_statement_list) = 0 then 
            bank_day_element := (date1+dayCounter,0);

        else
            bank_day_element := (date1+dayCounter,2);
            foreach statements_part_element in array temp_statements_part_array             
            loop 
                if statements_part_element.statement_last_transmission is null then
                    bank_day_element := (date1+dayCounter,1);                       
                    EXIT;
                end if;
            end loop;   
        end if;
    bank_day_array := array_append(bank_day_array,bank_day_element);
    end loop;
return bank_day_array;
END;
$get_bank_statements_downloadable_state$;
```

But it fails . It says the subquery must return only one column when I execute it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by using

```
    select array(select row(bast_id,bast_valuedate,bast_lasttransmission)
    into statements_part_array
    from bast_bankstatement
    inner join baac_bankaccount
    on bast_baac_id = baac_bankaccount.baac_id 
    where baac_folder_id = folderid
    and (bast_valuedate between date1 and date2)
    and bast_state = 1) 
    as statements_part_array;
```